# Json Transformation in java with high performance

Tags: java, json, transformation

I need to transform a Json into another Json according to the parameter coming as part of Rest request. This service is developed in Java. I know, Jackson API can be used easily and there are some libraries also available. But my requirement is to delivery response with new Json faster as much as possible.
If I can be given few option I can measure the performance of those.

Let's assume I have this Json in data storage:

```
{
    "bookId": "23228232-2dfa232",
    "bookName": "Json Transformation",
    "bookPublisher": "Tech Publication",
    "bookRating": [
        {
            "source": "All book rank",
            "maxRating": "10",
            "rating": "3.4"
        },
        {
            "source": "Tech Books",
            "maxRating": "5",
            "rating": "2"
        },
        {
            "source": "Popular",
            "maxRating": "3",
            "rating": "1"
        }
    ],
    "bookAuthor": [
        {
            "name": "Jone",
            "specialities": [
                "Json",
                "Javascript",
                "Typescript",
                "nodejs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "specialities": [
                "Java",
                "Spring",
                "ElasticSearch"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below rest calls should have respective results from this Json:
Get only authors

```
/authorName/23228232-2dfa232
{
    authorName: [
        "Jone",
        "Mike"
    ]
}
```

Get Average Rating

```
/popularity/23228232-2dfa232
{
    rating: "1.78"
}
```

So, the question is how to do this kind of transformation efficiently with any available library? As I mentioned above, I can simply use any Json library in Java and transform the Json, but I am not sure, if that will be efficient.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. What would really help in answering the question is if you could elaborate with an example, and also some sources you have researched to accomplish your task. The question seems to be somewhat open ended, which could be harder to answer. With some clarification, im sure someone will be able to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try little [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) java library for searching json data.

```
JsonValue json = JsonParser.parse(stringvariablewithjsondata);
List<JsonValue> authors = json.findAll(SPM.path("bookAuthor", "name")));
List<String> ratings = json.findAllLiterals(SPM.path("bookRating", "rating")));
```

and compute result like

```
JsonArray values = JsonFactory.array();
for(JsonValue value : authors) values.add(value);
JsonObject result = JsonFactory.object().add("authorName", values);
return result.toCompactString()
```

Comment: What will be performance of this transformation? will it higher than doing with Jackson or any Json lib in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON-Java --> https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json

Or the Google JSON, aka GSON and a few others as listed here --> https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/top-5-json-library-in-java-JEE.html

To see popularity and use statistics, which might help you chose which ones to test first: https://www.baeldung.com/java-json

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON as it easily maps JSON with POJO classes (Especially nested ones)
For a quick reference for performance  [comparison,](https://blog.overops.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/)